# Python, Pandas, SQLite : Loading a large table takes ages (more time than the actual DB extraction)

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am trying to load a 6GB table from an SQLlite Db to Python Pandas Dataframe with the following code:

```
sql_conn = sqlite3.connect(database_file, timeout=60) 
df = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT * from table""", sql_conn)
```

Opening the DB with DB Browser, running the same query and saving as CSV takes <1 minute.

**Problem: running my Python code takes +-30 minutes.**

Is there a reason (and a solution!) to why running the exact same query in Python/Pandas takes 30 times more time than it should?

Additional info: I'm using Pycharm. During the run, Pycharm consumes +-7GB of ram.
My laptop has 16g RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use chunk:

```
sql_conn = sqlite3.connect(database_file, timeout=60)
data = []
for chunk in pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT * from people""", sql_conn, chunksize=10000):
    data.append(chunk)
df = pd.concat(data)
```